# Is there a way to keep only as much history as needed for common ancestor between git repos?

Tags: git, sync, rsync

I'm currently using some decentralized git repos purely to speed up file syncs as compared to rsync. The speed up is significant, for example when there is 1GB of total changes in a large percentage of files in a 100GB folder, then rsync needs to read some more than this large percentage of 100GB on the source to sync and git push just 1GB.

The drawback is that this keep history and thus takes much more space than necessary.

How would I truncate history to only what is needed? I.e. there needs to be a common root commit between all the copies of the repo, but once there is a new common root the old one should be removed.

Maybe using shallow clones and adjusting depth of those clones dynamically, keeping track of where the current repo is synced to? Maybe combined with [this](http://git-annex.branchable.com/sync/) for making the decentralized part easier?

Comment: Don't use git for that if you don't want to store history. Git is not a sync tool, but a version control system

Comment: @frlan I use what works. Disk space is cheap, but slow and I value my time. I really don't want to wait orders of magnitude longer than necessary.